# how to change the color of all href tab with an id associated with it inside a d3 function and work for other html pages where the id is available

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, domdocument

I want to highlight rows that meet a condition as well as highlight an html tab with an id #htmlTab using d3

my code looks like this:

```
d3.rows.style('background-color', function(d){
if(row meets condition){
document.querySelector("#htmlTab").style.color = "orange";
return 'orange'}
 })
```

So at first d3 will highlight the rows if it meets the condition and then queryselector will color the #htmlTab. The problem I am having is that it is only changing the color of the the one tab that has the d3 table. I want it to color all the tabs that has an id #htmlTab on different pages as well. If this code is outside the d3.style function, it works for all the html tabs with that id: document.querySelector("#htmlTab").style.color = "orange";

Comment: The id attribute should be unique. Consider using a class for the tabs instead.

Comment: I tried using class, didn't work

Comment: What is d3.rows? I don't think d3 has a `.rows` function/property.

It's very unclear what you're trying to do. Please post more code around this code block or post a working codepen.

Comment: Also, d3 (or any JS code) can't have access to any other page apart from the current page.

Comment: Shreshth, that's what is seems to me like. Btw rows is just my variable. I included d3 before its be clear that i am using d3 but it's actually (rows.style())